# Python - pandas Avoid splitting string columns when writing to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is the sample of my code
when I write the dataframe into csv, `9 October 1937` and `81 years ago (1937-10-09)` are coming in different columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'established':['9 October 1937, 81 years ago (1937-10-09)','1996'],'location':['hyd','Delhi']})
df.to_csv('some_file.csv')
```

How to make `9 October 1937, 81 years ago (1937-10-09)` should be coming in same column??
Thanks

Comment: Your code works as intended without any changes for me (Windows 7, Python 3.6.4, Pandas 0.22.0).

Comment: It works fine on my system

Comment: You need to look into which csv dialect you want to target - one way or another you need to escape, or quote-surround that embedded comma, or some readers will interpret it as a delimiter.

Another option would be to force some alternative delimiter - but this is normally considered bad form - it's a faster alternative (if you can control the config of the downstream reader) but generally better to solve using the former mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKimber, it was because some configuration in my csv reader. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as it should, if you open the file in a plain text reader:

```
,established,location
0,"9 October 1937, 81 years ago (1937-10-09)",hyd
1,1996,Delhi
```

You may run into trouble when reading the .csv file afterwards, depending on how your reader handles the "," after 1937. It may understand it either as a field separator and cut right after, or understand that the encompassing quotes " ... " suggest that it is a single field.

To avoid any trouble you may want to use a semi-colon separator when writing the file: `df.to_csv("some_file.csv", sep=";")`